# Discord.js bot leave guild

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I make my bot leave a guild?
I tried this:

```
case `leave`:
    if(message.author.id !=='196701848239865866') 
        return message.channel.send(`**»** ${message.author}, you don't have permission to do that!`);
    var guildID = bot.guild.find()
    guildID.leave()
    break;
```

Comment: I can't really tell what the code is supposed to do. However, looking at it roughly, I can see a few mistakes. You can get the guild id through message.guild.id

Answer (score 11):

You cannot leave a guild by running `.leave()` from the guild id. I would suggest doing `message.guild.leave();` to leave the guild. If you need the guild id, you can get that from the message by doing `message.guild.id`.

To expand on why your code isn't working, there are a few things you are doing wrong.

`bot.guild` does not exist, therefore doing `bot.guild.find()` will not work either. Bots are designed to be in several guilds, therefore they are stored in a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) where you can search through them by doing `bot.guilds.find("id", guildId);`. Furthermore, once you have got the "id" it is returned as a [Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake), therefore it has no methods and you cannot run `.leave();` from it.

Answer (score 2):

In discord.js v12 you will have to use

```js
bot.guilds.cache.get(id).leave()
.catch(err => {
    console.log(`there was an error leaving the guild: \n ${err.message}`);
```

I think thats how it works! If you have any questions feel free to hmu!

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Splinxyy's answer, instead of `bot.guild.find();` (as it does not exist) try `message.guild`.

Answer (score 1):

Like they said above, `message.guild.leave()` would leave the current server from which the message was sent from. However, you can also use a similar method with the forEach algorithm. Here's an example: `bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {guild.leave()})` this would leave **ALL** servers in which your bot is in. If you want to leave a specific server with your bot, you could use something like this: `bot.guild.leave(server id here)`

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code I would say, do this:

```js
case `leave`:
    if(message.author.id !=='196701848239865866') 
        return message.channel.send(`**»** ${message.author}, you don't have permission to do that!`);
    var guildID = bot.guilds.cache.get(args[0]) //your argument would be the server id
    guildID.leave()
    break;
```

**If you want to make it leave the server the message is coming from, then do this:**

```js
    if(message.author.id !=='196701848239865866') 
        return message.channel.send(`**»** ${message.author}, you don't have permission to do that!`);
message.guild.leave()
```

Hope this helped.