# Trouble making a command to force bot to leave a server. (Discord,js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({ws: {intents: Discord.Intents.ALL}});
const botowner = 'xxx'

exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {
   let guildid = message.guild.id
 if (message.author.id = botowner) {
    toleave = client.get_server(guildid)
    await client.leave_server(toleave)
 } else {message.channel.send("You are not the bot owner")}
    
}

exports.help = {
    name: ['leavediscordserver']
    }
```

Whenever I run this code the following shows up:[image]

Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: well first of all `if (message.author.id = botowner)` thats not an if statement with only 1 `=`. That means that `get_server` does not exist on `client`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js bot leave guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844078/discord-js-bot-leave-guild)

Comment: "Not sure why this is happening." I am confused as to why you expected it to work. Take a look at the official documentation for `client` [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client). There's no `get_server()` method or `leave_server()` method in djs v12 or v13. You can't just make up a method name and expect it to work. Look at the docs and use the actual methods needed to do this. You'll have to access the guild cache via `client.guilds.cache`, then get the guild from there, as seen in the answers, like so: `client.guilds.cache.get(guildid)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you all you need to know. You attempt to use a function called `get_server()`, but this function does not exist ergo you cannot use it.

A discord server in Discord.js is referred to as a Guild so to get your guild you can just call `const guild = client.guilds.cache.fetch(guildid)` and to leave it all you have to do is call `guild.leave()`.

As a separate issue, a comparison in an if statement is made with 2 equal signs `==` not 1 as you did in your `if (message.author.id = botowner)` line.

Comment: You are kinda wrong because you also have to add `cache` before `fetch` in v12 or higher

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Crap, you're right. Must've been typing too fast haha.

Comment: It's fine, don't worry about it =3

Answer (score 0):

```js
var guildID = client.guilds.cache.get(args[0]) //your argument would be the server id
    if (message.author.id == botowner) { // use == to check if author and bot owner id match
    await guildID.leave() // waiting for bot to leave the server
 } else {message.channel.send("You are not the bot owner")}
    
}
```